# ignoreCommitterStrategy is not working in mutibranch job-dsl generator job

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

`enter code here`I'm trying to implement ignoreCommitterStrategy approach via multibranch generator job (i.e, job-dsl way)

I'm trying to implement ignoreCommitterStrategy approach via multibranch generator job (i.e, job-dsl way)
since we have too many existing multibranch-pipeline jobs and I try to achieve ignorecommitter stragegy inside branchsources of dsl.

After running seed job (i.e., multibranch generator job) I could see ignoreCommiter Strategy updated in existing multibranch pipeline jobs but still ignored author is not added. It means at this moment inside multibranch pipeline jobs -> config I have to manually click Add button and add ignored author list which is bit painful as we have many jobs.

```
buildStrategies {
   ignoreCommitterStrategy {
   ignoredAuthors("sathya@xyz.com")
   allowBuildIfNotExcludedAuthor(false)
   }
}
```

Note: I even tried with "au.com.versent.jenkins.plugins.ignoreCommitterStrategy"

Expecting IgnoredAuthor to be added into existing multibranch pipeline jobs upon execution of multibranch generator job

Answer (score 0):

Currently the build strategy can not be set by using [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL) because of [JENKINS-26535](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26535). But a fix is currently in review and will hopefully be released soon.

The correct syntax would be

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      buildStrategies {
        ignoreCommitterStrategy {
          ignoredAuthors('test@acme.org')
          allowBuildIfNotExcludedAuthor(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Until the problem has been fixed, you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to set the necessary options.